# Python Dash dropdown list with multiple visible row options

Tags: python, plotly-dash

Is is possible in python dash to create this:
HTML Example (reference https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_size.asp ):

```
<select id="cars" name="cars" size="3">
<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
<option value="saab">Saab</option>
<option value="opel">Opel</option>
<option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

I managed to create this so far in dash:

```
import dash
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import dash_html_components as html

app = dash.Dash(
    external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP]
)
   
app.layout = html.Div([
   html.Select([
        html.Option("Server1", id="Server1", value="Server1"),
        html.Option("Server2", id="Server2", value="Server2")
    ], id="connections", size=3,multiple='multiple'), ])   
if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run_server()
```

But how do I get selected values with @app.callback?

Comment: I have previously searched for the same problem and I think it's not possible. From what I found there's no way to detect which option was selected inside 'html.Select'. However you may able to obtain the number of clicks and when the last click was for each option and find the lastly selected option from there. I would suggest you to use plotly dropdown.

Comment: @ThaminduDJ Is it possible to have multiple visable rows with plotly dropdown or some other dash tool?

Comment: You can use ```multi``` property in plotly dropdown in order to allow the user to select more than one value at a time